# Bash: Group strings containing the same substring

Tags: shell-script

Let's imagine on the middle of a bash script I've an array of strings like this:

```
example1.log    
example1.log.1
log2.log
xpto.log
xpto.log.1
xpto.log.2
```

Is there way I can make it into an associative array containing the strings in a format like this (representation of the desired array structure):

```
{
    "example1" : [ "example1.log", "example1.log.1" ],
    "log2" : [ "log2.log" ],
    "xpto" : [ "xpto.log", "xpto.log.1", "xpto.log.2" ]
}
```

Notes:

- The initial strings will always have a format like `non-predictable-name` + `.log` + `.x` (optional dot and int number)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `bash` (version >= 4):

```
declare -A logs
for logfile in *; do
    logs[${logfile%%.*}]+="$logfile "
done
```

As an example of use of your associative array, you can print it like this:

```
for log in "${!logs[@]}"; do
    echo "$log:"
    for file in ${logs[$log]}; do
        echo "- $file"
    done
done
```

(I'm assuming none of your log files has a space in its name)

Comment: Keep in mind that `bash` associative arrays require at least v4.x of `bash`.

Comment: It should be noted that it assumes that `$IFS` contains the space characters, that the file names contain no character of $IFS and no wildcard characters (like with `foo bar.log` or `***.log`), and that the _non-predictable-name_ doesn't contain dots (like in `foo.bar.log.2`)

Comment: Thank you! your solution just works as expected. And no I won't get any spaces or extra dots. :)

Answer (score 1):

Though `bash` associative arrays were inspired from `ksh93`'s ones (with all their warts), it doesn't support assigning anything other than scalars to its values.

For an associative array whose values can be arrays, you need `ksh93`:

```
$ ksh -c 'typeset -A logs; for f in *.log*; do logs[${f%.log*}]+=($f); done; typeset -p logs'
typeset -A logs=([example1]=(example1.log example1.log.1) [log2]=(log2.log) [xpto]=(xpto.log xpto.log.1 xpto.log.2) )
```

To loop over them:

```
typeset -A logs
for f in *.log*; do logs[${f%.log*}]+=($f); done

for key in "${!logs[@]}"; do
  printf '%s:\n' "$key"
  for file in "${logs[$key][@]}"; do
     printf ' File: "%s"\n' "$file"
  done
done
```

`zsh` associative arrays can also only have scalar values, but since those values may contain the NUL character, they can store lists of arbitrary file names (by delimiting them with NUL characters). With `bash`, here as the file names are  all in the current directory, you can delimit with `/`. Or if you can make some assumption that a particular character doesn't occur in the file names (like @xhienne's approach with the space character), you can use that instead. Also note  that `bash` associative arrays have that limitation that the key can't be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat - <<\eof |
example1.log
example1.log.1
log2.log
xpto.log
xpto.log.1
xpto.log.2
eof
perl -lne '

/(.*)\.log(?=\.\d+$|$)/ and
   push(@{$h{$1}}, qq/"$_"/), $h[-1+keys %h]=$1;

END{

   print for 
      q/{/,

      join(",\n",
         map {
            join($",
               qq/\t"$_"/,
               q/:/,
               q/[/,
               join(", ", @{$h{$_}}),
               q/]/,
            )
         } @h
      ),

      q/}/

}
'
```

## Output

```
{
   "example1" : [ "example1.log", "example1.log.1" ],
   "log2" : [ "log2.log" ],
   "xpto" : [ "xpto.log", "xpto.log.1", "xpto.log.2" ]
}
```